# Adding a Comment to a Post without refreshing the page (like Instagram) Node.js, Express, Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to make a Instagram-like website and trying to add a comment to a post without refreshing the whole page, I am working with Node.js, Express, Mongoose. I am fairly new and I checked other similar questions but havent found anything that covered this very topic using the express framework.
I would be very thankful for your help!
Some of my code:

```
//Sending all the posts and their comments to the homepage
app.get("/", async function(req,res){
    //get all posts from db
    //this also somehow includes all the comments
    const allPosts = await posts.find({}).populate('comments');
    res.render("home", {posts: allPosts});
});
```

```
//comments being displayed under the image
<div class="container">
            <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
            <p class="card-text"><%= posts.description %></p>
            <% posts.comments.forEach(function(posts){ %>
                <p><strong><%= posts.comment.author %> - </strong><%= posts.comment.text %></p>
            <% }) %>
        </div>
```

```
//post Schema
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    image: String,
    description: String,
    comments: [
        {
           type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
           ref: "Comment"
        }
     ]
});
```